# How to sort TabItems in the TabControl

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol

I have a collection of type Page with an Order property, I set ItemsSource property of a TabControl an ObservableCollection. What I need to whenever I changed the Order property of an Entity 
the related TabItem go in the correct location.

WPF XAML :

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages.ListViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding Pages.Current}"  >
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:EditPageView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                    
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

C# Codes:

```
public class QuestionPageSection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Header { get; set; }
    private int _Order;
    public virtual int Order
    {
        get
        {
            return _Order;
        }
        set
        {
            _Order = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Order , PropertyChanged);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler  PropertyChanged;
}
```

I want to force TabControl to sort TabItems based on the Order property. So now I have these questoins:

- Is there any way to do it declaratively?
- Does TabControl have a SortColumn property?
- Does TabItem have a TabOrder property?
- Is there any type of collection that listen to its childs to automatically sort itself based on a property of childs??

Any other idea would be apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to sort the collection that your TabControl is bound to

I've always hated the fact that `ObservableCollection` doesn't have a built-in `Sort` method, so I usually use my own custom class that inherits from `ObservableCollection`

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollectionEx() : base() { }
    public ObservableCollectionEx(List<T> l) : base(l) { }
    public ObservableCollectionEx(IEnumerable<T> l) : base(l) { }

    #region IndexOf

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the index of the first object which meets the specified function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A bool function to compare each Item by</param>
    /// <returns>The index of the first Item which matches the function</returns>
    public int IndexOf(Func<T, bool> compareFunction)
    {
        return Items.IndexOf(Items.FirstOrDefault(compareFunction));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Sorting

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in ascending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in descending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    public void SortDescending<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderByDescending(keySelector));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in ascending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">An <see cref="IComparer{T}"/> to compare keys.</param>
    public void Sort<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        InternalSort(Items.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the items of the collection so that their orders are the same as those of the items provided.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortedItems">An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> to provide item orders.</param>
    private void InternalSort(IEnumerable<T> sortedItems)
    {
        var sortedItemsList = sortedItems.ToList();

        foreach (var item in sortedItemsList)
        {
            Move(IndexOf(item), sortedItemsList.IndexOf(item));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
ListViewModels = GetListViewModels();
ListViewModels.Sort(p => p.Order);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort you're ObservableCollection on the UI side by using CollectionViewSource.  Here's a link with examples:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried using CollectionViewSource, but it does not work. It sorts the list initaliy but does not responds to the changes that affect sort.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rachel, your solution gave me the clue, but still your solution is an answer because I can manually call the Sort method whenever I change the Order property, but I wanted to make it automatic. So I end up with a dynamic version of your code.

Based on the Rachel I approached to this solution.

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollectionEx() : base() { }

    public ObservableCollectionEx(List<T> l) : base(l) { }

    public ObservableCollectionEx(IEnumerable<T> l) : base(l) { }

    Func<IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable<T>> sortFunction;
    Action reset;

    #region IndexOf

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the index of the first object which meets the specified function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A bool function to compare each Item by</param>
    /// <returns>The index of the first Item which matches the function</returns>
    public int IndexOf(Func<T , bool> compareFunction)
    {
        return Items.IndexOf(Items.FirstOrDefault(compareFunction));
    }

    #endregion IndexOf

    #region Sorting

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in ascending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    public void SetSort<TKey>(Func<T , TKey> keySelector)
    {
        sortFunction = list => list.OrderBy(keySelector);
        InternalSort();
        reset = () => SetSort(keySelector);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in descending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    public void SetSortDescending<TKey>(Func<T , TKey> keySelector)
    {
        sortFunction = list => list.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        InternalSort();
        reset = () => SetSortDescending(keySelector);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in ascending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">An <see cref="IComparer{T}"/> to compare keys.</param>
    public void SetSort<TKey>(Func<T , TKey> keySelector , IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        sortFunction = list => list.OrderBy(keySelector , comparer);
        InternalSort();
        reset = () => SetSort(keySelector , comparer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the items of the collection in descending order according to a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract a key from an item.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">An <see cref="IComparer{T}"/> to compare keys.</param>
    public void SetSortDescending<TKey>(Func<T , TKey> keySelector , IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        sortFunction = list => list.OrderByDescending(keySelector , comparer);
        InternalSort();
        reset = () => SetSortDescending(keySelector , comparer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the items of the collection so that their orders are the same as those of the items provided.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalSort()
    {
        UpdateTracking(null , Items.ToList());
    }

    private void MoveItemToItsLocation(T item)
    {
        var sortListCache = sortFunction(Items).ToList();
        Move(IndexOf(item) , sortListCache.IndexOf(item));
    }

    #endregion Sorting

    public void UpdateTracking(IEnumerable<T> oldItems , IEnumerable<T> newItems)
    {
        if (sortFunction == null) return;

        PropertyChangedEventHandler changeTracker = (o , change) => { MoveItemToItsLocation((T)o); };
        Action<T> attachChangeTracker = o => o.ExecuteOnCast<INotifyPropertyChanged>(x => x.PropertyChanged += changeTracker);
        Action<T> detachChangeTracker = o => o.ExecuteOnCast<INotifyPropertyChanged>(x => x.PropertyChanged -= changeTracker);

        var greeting = new[] { attachChangeTracker , MoveItemToItsLocation };
        var farwell = new[] { detachChangeTracker };

        oldItems.ForEach(detachChangeTracker);
        newItems.ForEach(attachChangeTracker , MoveItemToItsLocation);
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);

        switch (e.Action) {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                UpdateTracking(e.OldItems.SafeGet(x => x.Cast<T>()) , e.NewItems.SafeGet(x => x.Cast<T>()));
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                UpdateTracking(Items.ToList() , null);
                if (reset != null)
                    reset();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I only made a little change to make it follow the changes in the underlying collection, so it will sort itself automatically after any changes made to underlying collection or any element in the underlying collection.